# Examples of application, used Android Backup Services

Tags: applications, backup, restore, backup-manager

Do you know any Android applications (with open source, if it's possible), which use Android Backup Service (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

I need examples, how Backup Service can be used in real applications.

Answer (score 4):

In your [Google account Dashboard view](https://www.google.com/dashboard/), in the **Andoid device** part you can see which applications stored someting in the Android backup service, for my account, beside the standard *Android Wallpaper*, *Android System Settings* and *Android Market* I have some *"Dragon, Fly! Free"* data (a game).

Comment: Do you have some other apps in that table?

Comment: @Hit : no, I have many other applications installed on different devices, and there are only 4 applications that appears on this table.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It's very strange, I have more then 160 apps on my Android, most of them from Top Paid or Top free, and none of them uses this great feature of Android OS